# NGINX container as a proxy for other docker containers

Tags: docker, nginx, unix, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have bind9 DNS server running as a container, and is mapped to port 53003 on the docker host:

```
version: "3"
services:
  DNS-SRV:
    container_name: DNS-SRV
    image: ubuntu/bind9
    ports:
      - "53003:53"
    environment:
      - TZ=UTC
    volumes:
      - ~/core/bind9/:/etc/bind/
```

and I wonder if I can use NGINX server as a proxy for it and other containerized services, here is my nginx.config file:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

stream {

    upstream dns_servers {
        server <docker_hostIP>:53003;
    }

    server {
        listen 53 udp;
        listen 53; #tcp
        proxy_pass dns_servers;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/dns.log info;
        proxy_responses 1;
        proxy_timeout   1s;
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to map any dns requests for the docker host on port 53 to port 53003, I'm not sure if there is another way:

Client -- DNS request ---> 53 (( [ NGINX ] --> 53003:53 ))

My setup isn't working, I'm testing it by doing nslookup like this:

```
# nslookup <domain> <docker_hostIP>
```

but I'm getting connection timed out, what could be the issue?

Comment: Typically you'd only use Nginx to serve or proxy HTTP requests, not other TCP or UDP protocols.  It's not obvious to me that this is a programming question, vs. a system-administration question; would another site like Server Fault be more appropriate for figuring out this setup?

Comment: So is the nginx listening on a different machine? In fairness nginx can be used as tcp and udp load balancer so saying only use is serve http requests is false. I won’t lie and say it’s not the most popular use case.

Comment: Both NginX and Bind9 containers reside on the same machine.

Comment: and both containers are using the same network "yamls_default", I tested adding another container to this network to see the connectivity, from this container, I'm able to reach bind9 container and even use it to resolve DNS, but not from the host machine.

Comment: Are you exposing the Nginx container to the host? cause from what I can see the host should have access to 53003 which obviously doesn't go through nginx

Answer (score 0):

You could do this?
Create a docker-compose incorporating both services

```
version: "3"
services:
  DNS-SRV:
    container_name: DNS-SRV
    image: ubuntu/bind9
    environment:
      - TZ=UTC
    volumes:
      - ~/core/bind9/:/etc/bind/
  NGINX:
    image: nginx:alpine
    ports:
      - "53:53/udp"
      - "53:53/tcp"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - "DNS-SRV"
```

Then in your nginx.conf do something like this?

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

stream {

    upstream dns_servers {
        server DNS-SRV:53;
    }

    server {
        listen 53 udp;
        listen 53; #tcp
        proxy_pass dns_servers;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/dns.log info;
        proxy_responses 1;
        proxy_timeout   1s;
    }
}
```

Comment: However, please note you might need to check if another service is using port 53:
sudo lsof -i :53